# TextBox and button Top Margin issue for Firefox and Chrome

Tags: html, css

Can someone fix the top margin issue occurring in Firefox and Chrome...Need to fix 2 pixel margin in both browsers...Kindly check the same in chrome and Firefox...

Here is the [link](http://jsfiddle.net/MP6CC/)...

```
.smalCopybtn{float:left;text-decoration: none;color: #23699A;border: solid 1px #ccc;background-color: #ddd;background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#ffffff), to(#dddddd));
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #ffffff,#dddddd);filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#dddddd');text-shadow:0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
font:normal 11px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;-webkit-border-radius: 2px; -moz-border-radius:2px;border-radius:2px; padding:2px 4px 2px 4px;}

.mleft5{margin-left:5px;}
.dvleft{float:left;}

.txtbx2{padding:2px;font-size:11px; border:solid 1px #c4c4c4;outline:none;transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out; -webkit-transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;-moz-transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;border-radius:2px;
-webkit-border-radius:2px;-moz-border-radius:2px; box-shadow:0 1px 6px rgba(0,0,0,.1) inset;-webkit-box-shadow:0 1px 6px rgba(0,0,0,.1) inset;-moz-box-shadow:0 1px 6px rgba(0,0,0,.1) inset}

a{text-decoration:none;color:#23699a;outline:none; cursor:pointer;}a:hover{text-decoration:underline;}


<span class="dvleft mleft5">
<input class="txtbx2" type="text" value="test value here" style="width: 280px" >
</span>
<a class="smalCopybtn" style="margin-left:-2px; margin-top:2px;">
<span style="padding-left:1px;">Copy</span>
</a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Remove**  `margin-top:2px;` **on your anchor link**

***[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohitazad/MP6CC/2/)***

### ------

**You write this**

```
<a class="smalCopybtn" style="margin-left:-2px; margin-top:2px;">
```

**Remove** `margin-top:2px;`

### -----------

**or add this**

```
.txtbx2{
vertical-align:top;
}
```

***[Updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohitazad/MP6CC/3/)***

Comment: Thanks.. Rohit... But did u checked in Chrome also.. Still little 1px bottom margin is showing...

Comment: Button is still disturbed one.Please check once again.

Comment: @RajivPingale Thanks for tell me i short this problum check this http://jsfiddle.net/rohitazad/MP6CC/3/

Comment: another solution...:- I have given margin:0px in textbox.. and removed margin-top:2px;...:) worked fine for me... Thanks all...

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking about a button got shifted 2px down then here is your solution.

In your CSS, remove float for smalCopybtn, that one was causing the problem.

Float has converted the  tag to display:block, but it should be display inline.

for more information about float and their effects, Please refer

http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/05/01/css-float-theory-things-you-should-know/

Comment: Still Not working in Firefox... But thanks for your time...@ Rohit Azad has found better solution...

Answer (score 0):

Why isn't your `<a>` tag inside a `<p>` or div or span or something?

Answer (score 0):

Rajivs' solution works -- Remove the `float:left` from your CSS; 
OR 
 
(Carols' solution) include the anchor inside a `<span> </span>`. ! Including the anchor in `<p> </p>` **doesn't work**, by the way!

**Tested in Firefox, Chrome and Safari.**